# DBGrid incremental search component

Tags: delphi, components, tdbgrid, incremental-search

I am looking into a improved DBGrid that allows me to search items only by pressing the keyboard without enetering data in the special search fields.

Any advanced functions such as colors will be great.

Comment: may be you can try onkeypress of the DBgrid the search code (same one in the special search field) and then execute it on pressing enter or somthing?

Comment: If you need some code to implement incremental search (including soundex search) on a grid, you can take a look at `TSQLTableToGrid.DrawGridKeyPress` in [this unit](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3UI.pas) and `TSQLTable.SearchValue` in [this other unit](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3Commons.pas). Some working open-source code which may help you implement your own version. In fact, upgrading a `TDrawGrid` to implement such features is very easy.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez i don't have any experience in modifying components could you point me to a tutorial or some component that is derived from this kind of control.It will help me very much. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to recommend [TDbGridEH](http://www.ehlib.com/dbgrideh1.htm) component. It is less popular than QuantumGrid but it is quite powerful one. Also it is somewhat easier to switch to it from standard TDBGrid compared to QuantumGrid.

Answer (score 1):

[DevExpress QuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/)